# Fetching breeze metadata is slow in Chrome, fast in IE

Tags: breeze

It appears that fetching metadata for my model is extremely slow in Chrome, but fast in IE.

My dbcontext contains around 35 entities with lots of navigation properties and each entity I add adds to the delay. Currently the delay is around 20 seconds, starting AFTER the query has returned the raw metadata, and it's entirely CPU which is working heavily, memory usage stays stable. I've got an i7 processor and ample memory.

I know there are differences in how the javascript engine is geared in these two browsers, with the chrome javascript JIT compiler being optimised for floating point operations (which is why webgl graphics are a thousand times faster in chrome than IE) - could this be having an impact on the work which fetchMetaData has to do?

Has anyone else noticed this slowness? Could it be that my relationships are wrong? Once the delay is over everything works though, so i'm doubting that relationships could be a problem.

Comment: Tested on the latest version by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the problem and solution!**

Thank you for taking the time to look at this, after your reply I decided to strip the whole project down to basics where I could reproduce the problem and look for any interference.

This was an older project in which I had implemented Breeze. The project used standard jquery post/get methods to get data from MVC, and since dates and times have always been a problem when posting and receiving json data from MVC I had this code in my startup script:

```
    // Add datafilter to jQuery ajax calls to translate dates
$.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function (data, type) {
    //if (type === 'json') {
    // convert things that look like Dates into a UTC Date string and completely replace them.
    data = data.replace(/(.*?")(\\\/Date\([0-9\-]+\)\\\/)(")/g,
                    function (fullMatch, $1, $2, $3) {
                        try {
                            return $1 + new Date(parseInt($2.substr(7))) + $3;
                        }
                        catch (e) { }
                        // something miserable happened, just return the original string
                        return $1 + $2 + $3;
                    });
    //}
    return data;
};
```

After removing this code (since breeze does dates properly), everything works as normal. This type of code may be common in other older projects which had to deal properly with dates, I know I got the above snippet from [WiredPrairie](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1183) and i'm sure others will also run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri, 
    I can't repro this, so I am wondering if there isn't something else involved.  Have you tried Firefox as well?